# RootBeer silently fails for large arrays?

Tags: cuda, rootbeer

I have a simple application that (for now) simulates error correction in a large array.

This bit generates the data and adds 16 bytes of Reed-Solomon parity to each block of 255 bytes.

```
ReedSolomonEncoder encoder = new ReedSolomonEncoder(QR_CODE_FIELD_256);
int[][] data = new int[params.getNumBlocks()][255];
int[][] original = new int[params.getNumBlocks()][];

int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < params.getNumBlocks(); i++) {
    int[] block = data[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 239; j++) {
        value = (value + 1) % 256;
        block[j] = value;
    }
    encoder.encode(block, 16);
    original[i] = Arrays.copyOf(block, block.length);

    // Corrupt a byte
    block[50] += 1;
}
```

This is my kernel:

```
public class RsKernel implements Kernel {
    private final int[] block;

    public RsKernel(int[] block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    @Override
    public void gpuMethod() {
        block[50] -= 1;
    }
}
```

it merely manually reverts the corrupted byte in each block (it doesn't do actual Reed-Solomon error-correction).

I run the kernels with the following code:

```
ArrayList<Kernel> kernels = new ArrayList<>(params.getNumBlocks());
for (int[] block : data) {
    kernels.add(new RsKernel(block));
}
new Rootbeer().run(kernels);
```

And I verify decoding with `JUnit`'s `assertArrayEquals`:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(original, data);
```

The curious bit is that if I run this code with up to 8192 (what a suspiciously convenient number) blocks (kernels), the data is reported to have been decoded correctly; for 8193 blocks and above, it is **not** decoded correctly:

```
Exception in thread "main" arrays first differed at element [8192][50]; expected:<51> but was:<52>
    at org.junit.Assert.internalArrayEquals(Assert.java:437)
    at org.junit.Assert.internalArrayEquals(Assert.java:428)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(Assert.java:167)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(Assert.java:184)
    at com.amphinicy.blink.rootbeer.RootBeerDemo.main(Jasmin)
```

What could cause this behaviour?

Here is the output of `java -jar rootbeer-1.1.14.jar -printdeviceinfo`:

```
device count: 1
device: GeForce GT 525M
  compute_capability: 2.1
  total_global_memory: 1073414144 bytes
  num_multiprocessors: 2
  max_threads_per_multiprocessor: 1536
  clock_rate: 1200000 Hz
```

Comment: I have the very same problem. Note that my GTX 760 has a hardware limit of 12288. And that is only the number of concurrent threads. It should be possible to send 2^32-1 threads to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I'm thinking it *may* be because the following:

```
// Corrupt a byte
block[50] += 1;
```

Could be adding one to 255, giving 256 which would not be a valid byte. Corrupting the byte might work better with something like this:

```
block[50] ^= 0x40;
```

Which would flip the bit in position 7 instead of adding to corrupt the byte.

Comment: That's a very good observation! I will correct my corruption code :) However, as you can see from the error message I added, you can see that it's not a byte-overflow situation (51 vs 52).